# Improvement over vector assignment and clear

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Many time I deal with this type of code:

```
vector<int>prev,cur;

for(i=1;i<n;i++){       

    //do some operation on cur based on prev vector

    prev = cur;

    cur.clear();
}
```

Is there any scope of time complexity improvement? As time complexity of clear is linear in terms of its element (container destructor is called), is there any way to do this operation on O(1) or less time by any other method? Should I use pointer to vectors then change pointer for doing

> prev  =  cur

Comment: [`vector::swap`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/swap/)

Comment: If space complexity dosn't matter use array of vectors.

Comment: Thanks, swap operation is really helpful.I didn't know about this before.And what would you suggest for clear operation.

Comment: @wrangler Generally I do have restriction on memory.Anyway thanks for suggestion.

Comment: `As time complexity of clear is linear in terms of its element (container destructor is called)` Not for `vector<int>` though, as the "destructor" of `int` is a no-op. If you look at the machine code generated for `clear()` call, I bet you'll find it just tweaks a pointer or two.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks! Actually I missed this part "This may be optimized to constant complexity for trivially-destructible types (such as scalar or PODs), where elements need not be destroyed."

Answer (score 1):

1) Your current way of doing it requires a copy of elements (which is O(n)) and the clearing of cur (in principle O(n) calls to destructor, but this shouldn't be a performance issue for basic types such as the `int` in your example).

2) The **[`swap()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/swap/)** recomended by [bhzad.nouri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/625914/behzad-nouri) in his comment exchanges the elements of the two vectors. From the point of view of performance, you can imagine this somewhat like an exchange of pointers.  Regardless how it is really implemented, the swap is done in constant time.   After the swap, you nevertheless have data in `cur`, so you might need to `clear()` it.

3) pointers to vectors would look ugly.  The vector swap comes to the same result in terms of performance and is so much more elegant !

Comment: Thanks this helped, So is it best to use swap (that will take constant time ) after that clear on cur.So overall one linear scan.Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use move semantics over swap:

```
for(i=1;i<n;i++){       

    //do some operation on cur based on prev vector

    prev = std::move(cur);

    cur.clear();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for suggestion but as documentation suggests move will take linear time to move the element and after that cur is still not empty, its element will be in some undefined state.So I need to perform clear on cur that will also take the linear time, So how will this improve over the method that I have suggested in question?Basically this will also take 2 linear scan.Please correct me if I am wrong.